# Intel Galileo adding kernel header files to the cross compile toolchain

Tags: linux, kernel, yocto, toolchain, intel-galileo

im on BSP v1.1
yocto is 1.6

I'm trying to set up the cross compile toolchain to compile character driver code
but the output i get is

[mark@localhost ~]$ ${CC} first.c -o first

> first.c:1:24: fatal error: linux/init.h: No such file or directory
>
> .#include 
>                                            ^ compilation terminated.

I think the issue is that
the header is not in the toolchain
/opt/iot-devkit/1.6.1/sysroots/i586-poky-linux/usr/include/linux/~
there is no  at this location

I think something has to be added as  IMAGE_INSTALL or IMAGE_FEATURE but i dont know what

am I on the right track ?
does anyone know what i have to add ?
or am i completely off tracks altogether?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first and foremost, you can *never* build a kernel module by just running ${CC} on it. You should always use a Makefile, which redirects most of its work to the kernel source Makefil.

Create a Makefile for you module, consisting of something similar to:

```
obj-m += hello-1.o

all:
    make -C  $(KERNEL_SRC M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C  $(KERNEL_SRC) M=$(PWD) clean
```

Example taken from [The Linux Kernel Module Programming Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/x181.html) (Note that the actual commands needs to have a tab character for indentation).

Then you'll have to define KERNEL_SRC to be `/opt/iot-devkit/1.6.1/sysroots/i586-poky-linux/usr/src/kernel/`, either in the Makefile, or from your make call. (Using a variable like KERNEL_SRC will ensure that your module recipe automatically picks the right location when building using bitbake).

To manually build your kernel module:

1. Source the environment-* file for your SDK.
2. Go to you modules directory.
3. KERNEL_SRC=/opt/iot-devkit/1.6.1/sysroots/i586-poky-linux/usr/src/kernel LDFLAGS="" make
   However, this will fail, as fixdep can't be found. We'll fix this manually.
4. cd /opt/iot-devkit/1.6.1/sysroots/i586-poky-linux/usr/src/kernel
5. make silentoldconfig scripts
6. Go back to your modules directory.
7. KERNEL_SRC=/opt/iot-devkit/1.6.1/sysroots/i586-poky-linux/usr/src/kernel LDFLAGS="" make

This should now produce hello.ko which you should be able to insmod on the Galileo board.

Comment: When i do no 7. i get back 


CC [M]  /home/mark/GalileoDriver/hello-1.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
/bin/sh: scripts/mod/modpost: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** [__modpost] Error 127
make[1]: *** [modules] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/opt/iot-devkit/1.6.1/sysroots/i586-poky-linux/usr/src/kernel'
make: *** [all] Error 2
`
Any suggestion?

Comment: Did step 5 work out OK? `scripts/mod/modpost` should have been created at that point, together with e.g. `scripts/basic/fixdep`.

Comment: well to be honest i kept hitting enter 
will i run again ?

Comment: I have another question up if you would be able to help me

Comment: Sure, just ask. Though maybe it should be a new question? Another possibility is to take out on the Yocto Project mailing list.

Comment: I SCPed the file to the Galileo and insmod it 

my issue now is it's saying I have the wrong format.
 
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module hello-1.ko: Invalid module format

Comment: Well, look at the standard things... Double check the arch of the hell0-1.ko, run modinfo on the module and verify everything. Double check the .config file in /opt/iot-devkit/1.6.1/sysroots/i586-poky-linux/usr/src/kernel with the one belonging to the running kernel. Is CONFIG_MODVERSIONS (and friends) enabled or not?